# 'Forgot Email' function not sending email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm building my first ASP.NET Core Razor Pages application.

I have created an `EmailSender` class, which implements `IEmailSender`.

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private readonly EmailSettings Settings;

    public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailSettings> emailSettings)
    {
        Settings = emailSettings.Value;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Host = Settings.Host;
            client.Port = Settings.Port;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.UserName, Settings.Password);
            client.EnableSsl = Settings.EnableSsl;

            message.To.Add(email);
            message.From = new MailAddress(Settings.FromAddress);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = htmlMessage;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            await client.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And I've registered `EmailSender` in Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Default initialization...

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
}
```

My code builds with no errors.

Using breakpoints, I can see that when I run the application and click *Forgot your Password*, the `EmailSender` constructor is called and the `EmailSettings` instance has the expected values. And when I enter my email address and click *Reset Password*, the `EmailSender` constructor is called a second time. However, `EmailSender.SendEmailAsync()` is *never* called, and no email is sent.

I'm convinced my `EmailSender` class is setup right because the constructor is being called. But I don't know how to isolate the reason `SendEmailAsync()` is never called.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm not seeing any code which calls `SendEmailAsync`. Where is this method called from?

Comment: @DeanOC: My understanding is that it is called from ASP.NET. I selected the option for my application to have a local user repository and, in fact, it produced pages that include a *Forget my Password* link, which goes to a page that prompts for your email. Unfortunately, I have no way to debug that code or even view the markup (???) for it.

Comment: @DeanOC: The `EmailSender` class in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) seems to assume it will be called from ASP.NET as well. And, in fact, the framework is apparently creating an instance of the class as demonstrated by the fact that my constructor is being called.

Comment: In the link you pasted, there is a feedback issue #15830 about emails not being sent. Is that relevant to you?

Comment: @DeanOC: Good find, as I would've never expected that. Unfortunately, setting the `EmailConfirmed` column to true doesn't change the result. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Scaffold Identity

You need to scaffold Identity in order to debug the code.

Right click on the Identity folder and then click

- Add >> New scaffolded item..

In the left menu click

- Identity >> Add

Then

- Check Account\ForgotPassword
- Choose your DB Context class
- Click add

Now you have your razor page with code behind so click on the arrow to expand the code behind file.

In the `PostAsync()` put a breakpoint on the if statement.

```cs
if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))) // Breakpoint here
{
    ...
}
```

Run the application and do a Forgot Password request.

Your breakpoint will hit and you will be able to debug. It will not exit the if-statement because await `_userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)` is **false**.

Solve that problem by dragging the debugger outside of that loop, and let it continue. Now you will see that your Email sender will be called and your SendEmailAsync will hit.

#### To sum it up

- The 'magic' login, logout and account pages are provided to you by the Identity Team through a library package.
- In order to access the code you need to scaffold them.
- You weren't hitting the `SendEmailAsync` because the user you tried to request a password for was either non-existent *or* most likely, your user's email wasn't confirmed!

Comment: I don't understand this. My application already has a Register page, a Login page, a Forgot Password page, and so on. And everything seems to work except for sending the Forgot Password email. It seems to me these pages are already set up for me. But apparently they are implemented within the framework. So I'm confused by the suggestion that I need to scaffold Identity.

Comment: Identity hides these pages from you. They are part of the Identity UI. In order to access them - and make changes to them or debug them - you have to scaffold the code.

Comment: I'll look into this in the morning. It's the first I've heard that this additional step is needed, so I need to see if I can find some documentation about it.

Comment: Of course. [You can read it here..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: So, I was able to spend some time on this. Looks like I need to add MVC in order for the steps above to work. I was feeling really good about Razor Pages. Is it really necessary to add MVC controllers in order to customize Identity?

Comment: Are you talking about the scaffolding of the Identity UI? - Then yes, in order to make any changes to them it is necessary to scaffold them first.

Comment: My question was about MVC. I was feeling really good about Razor Pages and how clean they seem. In order to implement the steps above (scaffolding Identity), it looks like I have to add MVC.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'it looks like I have to add MVC'?

Comment: I don't have the details in front of me, but if I follow your steps above, I get a run-time error. Reading more at the link you provided, I see a TXT file is created when I scaffold parts of Identity. That file talks about the changes made, and has additional instructions in order for the scaffolding to work. Those instructions include changes to Startup.cs, which include adding `AddMvc()`. Apparently, the scaffolding generates code that uses MVC.

Comment: I get it. That's been taken care of in .Net Core 3.0. You can just call `.AddRazorPages()` instead. See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services)  by Microsoft

Answer (score -1):

Please confirm that your `AccountController` invokes the `IEmailSender.SendEmailAsync` method. See here for an example: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/identity/sample/src/ASPNETCore-IdentityDemoComplete/IdentityDemo/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L375

There is a line in the `ForgotPassword` action:

```c#
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Reset Password",
                   $"Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
```

Comment: I don't see any controllers in Razor Pages. Moreover, as I mentioned in my question, I can't even see the markup for the membership pages (Register, Login, Forgot Password, etc.) I have no idea how I could modify those pages or the behavior behind them.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forget Razor Pages is different. Your project should have a `Pages` folder. More specifically it should have `Pages / Account / Manage`. Each `cshtml` file there should have an associated `cs` file with the "code behind".

Comment: It doesn't have any of those pages. Under *Areas*, it has an *Identity* folder. But the only file there is *_ViewStart.cshtml*. Everything else must be in ASP.NET. Personally, I don't get it. That's just something else I need to figure out about Razor Pages.

Comment: you can see it document:
https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aspnetcore-login-registration-example @JonathanWood

Comment: @RezaGhahari: Looks like that's the code. But if it's embedded within ASP.NET, how do I customize it for my application?